# 'Double' is not convertible to 'CGFloat?'

Tags: swift, cgfloat

My Xcode keeps giving me a Double is not convertible to CGFloat error. Thing is the error keeps moving whenever I change the code. At first it was on this line:
`Text("left") .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0, alignment: .center)` where I set the height to 100.0 now it is at the bottom:`TextField("example", text: "PLACEHOLDER") .frame(width: 300.0, height: 300.0, alignment: .center)` at the height.

On the apple dev site it says for swiftUI as an example:
`.frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .topLeading)`
I tried removing the decimals and I get an Int is not convertible to CGFloat.
At one point I tried to put CGFloat() around each and I got a 'CGFloat is not convertible to CGFloat?' error

Any help is appreciated thank you

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

HSplitView{
    VStack{
        Text("left")
            .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0, alignment: .center)
        Text("left bottom")
            .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0, alignment: .center)
        Text("leftbottombottom")
            .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0, alignment: .center)
    }
    TextField("example", text: "PLACEHOLDER")
        .frame(width: 300.0, height: 300.0, alignment: .center)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try casting `Double` to `CGFloat`:

```swift
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

HSplitView{
    VStack{
        Text("left")
            .frame(width: CGFloat(100.0), height: CGFloat(100.0), alignment: .center)
        Text("left bottom")
            .frame(width: CGFloat(100.0), height: CGFloat(100.0), alignment: .center)
        Text("leftbottombottom")
            .frame(width: CGFloat(100.0), height: CGFloat(100.0), alignment: .center)
    }
    TextField("example", text: "PLACEHOLDER")
        .frame(width: CGFloat(300.0), height: CGFloat(300.0), alignment: .center)
}
```

Depending on the type and language, you may have to explicitly cast one type to another rather than expecting the language to implicitly coerce it for you.

Comment: This is what I feel like would be the correct answer, but I'm pretty sure he said he did that, and got some weird error. It sounds like something else strange is going on.

Comment: When I copy and pasted the suggested code I got this time: 'Generic parameter 'C0' could not be inferred' at the start of the  VStack

Answer (score 1):

SwiftUI sometimes reports wrong errors, as is the case here. Your problem is that you have a type error in `TextField("example", text: "PLACEHOLDER")`. The second argument should be a binding, not a string. This works:

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

struct MyView: View {
  @State var text = "PLACEHOLDER"

  var body: some View {
    HSplitView{
      VStack{
        Text("left")
          .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0, alignment: .center)
        Text("left bottom")
          .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0, alignment: .center)
        Text("leftbottombottom")
          .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0, alignment: .center)
      }
      TextField("example", text: $text)
        .frame(width: 300.0, height: 300.0, alignment: .center)
    }
  }
}
```